# Сохранение кеша в LoadingObjectManager

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите, возможно ли сохранить кеш в случае если `LoadingObjectManager` удаляется/скрывается с карты и затем обратно добавляется (тот же самый экземпляр)? Проблема в том что в случае удаления с карты отрабатывает `onRemoveFromMap` который очищает `_dataLoadController` в котором и хранятся все данные кеша.

Пробовал по разному переназначать методы, но ничего путного не вышло.

Суть в том что у меня есть 2 `LoadingObjectManager` которые по переменно надо менять на карте, но надо что бы сохранялись уже загруженные данные, чего не происходит.